# Subversion merge failing

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am seeing something I don't understand while merging code from a Subversion branch.

We have an 'experimental' branch, where we implemented a fix for some functionality. We begun the branch work with:

```
svn cp https://..../trunk https://.../branches/experimental
```

We proceeded to hack on the experimental branch for the last two weeks, while normal development proceeded as usual on the trunk. Work on the branch occured only on a specific "root" folder (usermngmt-II).

Now it is time to merge the branch work back in the trunk. The problem exhibited during merging can be described as: "a file that never changed in the experimental branch, fails to merge cleanly in the trunk".

Starting from a working folder that mirrors the trunk's version of the folder...

```
$ cd workOnTrunk
$ svn info
Path: .
URL: https://x.x.x.x/.../trunk/usermgmnt-II
...
$ svn update
At revision 4900.

$ svn status
$
```

...we execute the merge command:

```
$ svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/experimental/usermgmnt-II/
Conflict discovered in 'webservices/usermngmt-ws-api/src/java/gr.neuropublic.gaia.usermngmt.ws.api/IUserMngmtService.java'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: df
--- /tmp/svn-9vbG0j     Πεμ Απρ 11 11:27:54 2013
+++ webservices/usermngmt-ws-api/src/java/gr.neuropublic.gaia.usermngmt.ws.api/.svn/tmp/IUserMngmtService.java.8.tmp    Πεμ Απρ 11 11:27:54 2013
@@ -49,7 +49,16 @@

     public Pair<Integer, String> numOfUsers();

+<<<<<<< .working
+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allSubsInfo();

+=======
+>>>>>>> .merge-right.r4900
+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allGaiaSubsInfo();
+
+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> subsUsersInfo(int subs_id);
+
+
     @Local
```

So subversion reports that the 'working' version - that is, the version in our working folder (which as we saw above, mirrors the "trunk") is reported to have the line...

```
public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allSubsInfo();
```

...inside it, while the version in the experimental branch (if I am deciphering the merge conflict message correctly) is reported by subversion to (a) not have the "allSubsInfo" line in place, and (b) but have two others instead:

```
public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allGaiaSubsInfo();
public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> subsUsersInfo(int subs_id);
```

However, this is not the case - to prove it, we use "svn cat" to print the contents of the file in the experimental branch, and grep for the reported methods:

```
$ svn cat ^/branches/experimental/usermgmnt-II/webservices/usermngmt-ws-api/src/java/gr.neuropublic.gaia.usermngmt.ws.api/IUserMngmtService.java | grep 'all.*SubsInfo'
$
```

It is clear that the "conflicted" file, in its form in the "experimental" branch, has no instance of either "allSubsInfo" or "allGaiaSubsInfo". In fact, the output file generated via the "svn merge" command...

```
$ grep allSubsInfo  IUserMngmtService.java.merge-right.r4900
$
```

...doesn't either. In fact, if we just plain extract the two versions of the files:

```
$ svn cat -r4900 ^/branches/experimental/usermgmnt-II/webservices/usermngmt-ws-api/src/java/gr.neuropublic.gaia.usermngmt.ws.api/IUserMngmtService.java > /var/tmp/experimental.java
$ svn cat ^/trunk/usermgmnt-II/webservices/usermngmt-ws-api/src/java/gr.neuropublic.gaia.usermngmt.ws.api/IUserMngmtService.java > /var/tmp/trunk.java
$ diff -u /var/tmp/experimental.java /var/tmp/trunk.java
--- /var/tmp/experimental.java  2013-04-11 11:49:13.000000000 +0300
+++ /var/tmp/trunk.java 2013-04-11 11:49:58.000000000 +0300
@@ -49,6 +49,13 @@

     public Pair<Integer, String> numOfUsers();

+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allSubsInfo();
+
+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> allGaiaSubsInfo();
+
+    public Pair<List<Map<String, String>>, String> subsUsersInfo(int subs_id);
+
+
     @Local
     public interface ILocal extends IUserMngmtService {}
```

...we see that the version in the trunk simply added 3 lines. The "merge" process, therefore, as far as the version of this file in the experimental branch is concerned, should have been a "no-op" - "nothing was commited in this file in the experimental branch, leave it be".

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

P.S. In case it is important, we are using Subversion 1.6 - more spefically: version 1.6.11 on the server, and on my client machine I use the command line interface, version 1.6.17. The problematic behaviour is also exhibited when using the latest TortoiseSVN, too (so I tend to doubt that this is version specific).

Comment: have you merged trunk changes to your branch before reintegration?

Comment: @maxim1000: attempting to merge trunk's version of "usermgmnt-II" into the experimental branch (without --reintegrate), shows exactly the same conflict: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5362364

Comment: Merge `trunk` into `experimental`, take `trunk`'s version of the conflicted file, then merge `experimental` back into trunk?

Comment: @Sameer: As I said to maxim1000, merging the trunk into the experimental shows the same illogical conflict: a file that was never touched in the experimental branch, cannot "fast-forward" (to use git terminology) via the trunk commits (i.e. end up exactly the same as the trunk version). See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5362364

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from commands you listed, "experimental" was branched from trunk, but you try to reintegrate "experimental/usermgmnt-II". This may be the source of the problem.

Comment: I do not believe this is correct - merges are supposed to take into account the commits done to the relevant subtree, so what difference does it make that I originally copied the entire source tree? Note that I am merging the corresponding versions of a specific folder (i.e. in the branch and in trunk), so the reason you are attributing the failure to, should have (in theory) have zero impact. It definitely has no impact in other VCS.

Comment: My guess was that "experimental/usermgmnt-II" is tried to be merged to "trunk" instead of "trunk/usermgmnt-II".